# Simple_form can't find path for instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I get this in my form:

```
undefined method `urls_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000048ec778>:0x00000005583090>
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for @url, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= f.input :url %>
<%= f.input :contact_name %>
<%= f.input :contact_email %>
```

In my controller action I do, `@url = Url.new`

I have another app, that does things in the way way, so I don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your routes are correct, run

> rake routes

you should see

> urls GET  /    urls#index

Comment: I have this: `url_index GET    /url(.:format)                 url#index`

Comment: you should define the routes with "resources :urls" seems that you have url_index_path instead urls_path

Comment: thanks, you were on the right page. I also had my controllers named in singular.